# I want to repeat the code if the condition is false

Tags: c

Can anyone tell me the mistake in this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a=5, i=0, j;
    while(a<1 && a>8)
    {
        printf("Height:");
        scanf("%d",&a);
    }
    for(i=0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(j=a; j>i+1; j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=i+1; j>0; j--)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

here is there a mistake in the while loop? i thought it would prompt the user for height again if the condition is true

Comment: Please try to explain the condition `a<1 && a>8` to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is basic mathematics: a number cannot be smaller than 1 and bigger than 8 at the same time.

You used `&&` (logical AND) instead of `||` (logical OR).

Comment: There's also the error of initializing `a` to 5. The while loop won't execute, meaning the input is never taken

Comment: True, and that is his next step to debug. Maybe even ask a new question here :) Right now, `a` can be initialized to any value, the loop will still not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is never true according to your conditions.
    To prompt the user to enter height ,you have to use OR 
    condition in the while loop not the AND  condition.
    You can declare like this to make your code work

`

```
 int a=5;
     while(a<1 || a>8){
     printf("Height:");
     scanf("%d",&a);
       }
```

`